# PHP headers only work if html form is completely filled

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, post, header

I have tried to make a page for a user to input some information (first name, last name); however, the user can also choose not to input any information in the HTML form and can click the submit button leaving it blank.  The page takes either the user given data or creates default data if the user has left the HTML form blank and inputs it into a MySQL table.

After processing the MySQL data, it redirects to another page using a PHP header.  The other page has an identical goal, but different data (job title, employer name).  The difference in the second page is that it has two submit buttons- one that allows the user to add another set of data(job title, employer name), and another one to redirect it to the next page.

I have had success with the first page's collection of user-created data, and, if left blank, it processes the default MySQL data. It then redirects to the next page successfully. On page 2, it can only process completed user data in the HTML form, but if anything is left blank(or if the form is totally blank), it won't process the default data and simply redirects back to itself without processing MySQL.

I don't know why page 2 won't process the default data, and then redirect to page 3.

The require once at the beginning of each page(pdo.php) is simply creating the pdo object and connection.

I simplified the code here:

Page 1:

```
<?php
     session_start();
     require_once "pdo.php";
         if (isset($_POST['first_name']) &&
             isset($_POST['last_name']))
            {
              $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Users (first_name,             
                       last_name)
                       VALUES(:first_name,             
                              :last_name)";

              $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
              $stmt1->execute(array(
                         ':first_name' =>    
                         (empty($_POST['first_name']))  
                          ? 'NoFirstNameGiven' : 
                          $_POST['first_name'],
                         ':last_name' => 
                          (empty($_POST['last_name']))  
                          ? 'NoLastNameGiven' : 
                          $_POST['last_name']));

              header("Location: page2.php");
              exit;
            }
  ?>
```

And Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";

     if (isset($_POST['job_title']) &&
        isset($_POST['employer_name'])) 
              {

                   $sql = "INSERT INTO Employment   
                   (job_title, employer_name)
                   VALUES(:job_title, :employer_name)";

                   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                   $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':job_title' =>    
                        (empty($_POST['job_title']))  
                        ? 'NoJobTitleGiven' : 
                        $_POST['job_title'],

                       ':employer_name' =>   
                       (empty($_POST['employer_name'])) 
                       ? 'NoEmployerGiven' :  
                       $_POST['employer_name']));

                  if(isset($_POST['nextButton'])){
                       header("Location: page2.php");
                       exit;
                     }
                  if(isset($_POST['add_job'])){
                       header("Location: page3.php");
                       exit;
                    }
              }
  ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a syntax error on page2 on `if (isset($_POST['job_title'])`, it's probably missing a `&&` just like page1.

Comment: I edited the code up top- the syntax error isn't there in the original code.  Thank you for pointing that out.  The first page still only processes the blank data.

Comment: Then it should work. Are you sure that `job_title` and `employer_name` are both set? Do they show in `var_dump($_POST);` ?